# Google Cloud Image exporting blurry and small tiff images

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, hyperspectral-sensor

I'm trying to export a image from GEE. For some reason, I'm getting a very small image size that is only `21x30` in dimensions.

I'm trying to read it in Python and QGIS. Same problem in both platforms

GEE Code:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: filtered_region,
  folder:"pixxel",
  region: geometry,
  scale:30,
  fileFormat: "GeoTIFF"
})
```

Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b79441422defdf9a7ec08ca75cedccbf

Python Visual Output:

[image]

Why is it getting exported in this way?